# From which tensorflow version onwards can quantization be applied?

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently using tensorflow 1.14 for pruning, but I am not sure if I can apply quantization on the same version. Please help.
On pruning tensorflow guide page, the below was mentioned

> TensorFlow versions: TF 1.x for versions 1.14+ and 2.x.
> But this part is missing in the quantization page.

This [page](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization) mentions explicitly that *post training quantisation* can be applied on tensflow 1.15.

Can you please confirm that if quantization can be only applied from tensorflow 1.15 onwards or are there any alternatives for older versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TensorFlow versions: TF 1.x for versions 1.14+ and 2.x.

This means, tensorflow version should be greater than `1.14` in `TF 1.x` and all versions in `TF 2.x`.

The same has mentioned even on [post-training quantisation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization) page, as `the procedures on this page require TensorFlow 1.15 or higher`.

There are two forms of quantization: post-training quantization and quantization aware training

If you are looking for solution in `TF 1.14`, then you have to fallback on `tf.contrib` module. There you can quantization using `Quantization-aware training`. For more details you can refer [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.14/tensorflow/contrib/quantize).

But the problem you may have limitations depending on use case because bugs discovered here are less likely to be addressed.